# Shibboleth Errors When Authenticating Through a Reverse Proxy on port 8000

Tags: apache, shibboleth

Trying to get shibboleth working on a Docker container, using Apache as a reverse proxy. Problems occur because I am using port 80 for the public Apache instance and port 8000 for the internal instance, which confuses shibboleth:

```
2017-10-03 07:34:23 ERROR OpenSAML.MessageDecoder.SAML2POST [5]: POST targeted at (https://dashboard.hpc.unimelb.edu.au/Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/POST), but delivered to (https://dashboard.hpc.unimelb.edu.au:8000/Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/POST)
```

The first URL is the external URL which the end user sees. The second URL is what the docker container sees when it gets the proxied request (with the HTTP host name forwarded).

Note I used "ShibURLScheme https" on the internal apache instance to ensure it believes https is being used, as the reverse proxy ensures all requests are https.

Is there anyway I call tell Shibboleth that this is OK, the URLs really are the same? Maybe by rewriting the URL shibboleth sees or something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are two things I would check:

1. Make sure the `ServerName` directive in your Apache conf file is set to 
   `https://dashboard.hpc.unimelb.edu.au:80`. Notice the `:80`. Omitting 
   the port number completely may work too. You want Apache and vis-a-vis, shibd to see the `ServerName` that the client is using. You should also make sure you have a `UseCanonicalName On` directive as part of this.
2. This is likely less of a problem, but make sure your sp-metadata given to the IdP is correct. [You should add entries for the FQDN(s) that the client sees.](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/SPReverseProxy#SPReverseProxy-Metadata) Please note that most of that documentation page isn't applicable to your scenario, but adding the correct metadata entries is vital.

It looks like your `ServerName` in Apache isn't correct, so I'd start there.

Comment: The Apache config already has ``ServerName dashboard.hpc.unimelb.edu.au:8000`` :-(. Also I know the SP metadata is correct, this is an existing good setup that I am attempting to convert to Docker. I think the problem is that the SP meta data says port 80 (correct, this is the external port) but the internal Apache instance is on 8000.

Comment: @PenguinBrian How did you solve this in the end? Also trying to proxy Shibboleth SP with Apache proxy. Seems like setting the ServerName does the trick.

Comment: I did get it going but it was a real kludge. e.g. IIRC needed apache to listen to http on port 443 just to convince the shibboleth library the connection was secure. But I don't like putting Apache in a Docker container. And Apache is the library that supports shibboleth. The many saml libraries don't support the required API, and I have no time to fix. So I ended up using https://rapid.aaf.edu.au/ - which feels like a kludge also (count the redirects to login!), but maybe a simpler kludge. Basically a shibboleth wrapper service that exposes a JWT interface.